# how to only render pageView pages after the sliding animation is over

Tags: flutter, dart, pageviews

in my app I use heavy pages that have a lot to show, images to render and more, when sliding what happens is that my sliding animation will stagger while my page is being rendered mid swipe, I want to minimize this effect.

I want to have the page, by default, display a certain widget(preferably a single container with a bg color, or a shimmer, or any placeholder I can choose), and then when the sliding animation is finished the data which is being computed in the background will appear. like this, I won't have to see the janky animation when swiping.

is there any way of doing this, other than having to manually use streambuilders  to listen for the pageView controller?

Comment: Please share the code for PageView!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, [preload_page_view](https://pub.dev/packages/preload_page_view), pageview outside screen will be preloaded~

[EDITED]
Alternative, What if you only put context When index == onchangedIndex, something like,

```
int _currentIndex = 0;

PageView.builder(
  onPageChanged: (index){
    //Even you can use here Future.delay to delay a second after onPageChanged, if loading your content is too quick
                              setState(() {
                                _currentIndex = index;
                              });
                            },
  itemBuilder: (context, index){
    return _currentIndex == index ? //your content : Container(/*with background color*/);
}
```

Comment: i actually tried this but it does have a bad take on the performance and "jankiness" of my app

Answer (score 0):

Add a delay to the Pages, equal to the animation duration of PageView.

1.Create a variable,

```
final duration = Duration(milliseconds: 600);
```

2.Add delay to the Page(),

```
Future.delayed(duration, () => Page() );
```

3.Animate to a different page,

```
_pageController.animateToPage(
  1,
  duration: duration,
  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
);
```

Comment: this doesn't help a lot if i don't have manual control over the sliding. also I can't get or set the swipe speed on the controller of the pageview

Comment: Can you share the cope for PageView?